# How can I import an input from one file to another and synchronize it?

Tags: python, file-io

I want to synchronize my input in one file with the variables in another file. Where should I put my return statement in the login function in order to import variables to another file and synchronize there?

I have tried to put return username, password inside the login function and import that login function in other file and get the variables

```
class main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Window
        self.master = master
        # Some Usefull variables
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.n_username = StringVar()
        self.n_password = StringVar()
        # Create Widgets
        self.widgets()

    # Login Function
    def login(self):
        # Establish Connection
        with sqlite3.connect('quitq.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        return self.username, self.password  ### this one I added to try to send other file

        # Find user If there is any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?')
        c.execute(find_user, [(self.username.get()), (self.password.get())])
        result = c.fetchall()
        if result:
            self.logf.pack_forget()
            self.head['text'] = self.username.get() + '\n Loged In'
            self.head['pady'] = 150
            top1.deiconify()

        else:
            ms.showerror('Oops!', 'Username Not Found.')
```

This is the main file where I tried to use return statement in order to use in the following code:

```
import datetime
import email
import imaplib
import menu

username, password = menu.main.login()

a = username
b = password

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = a
PASSWORD = b
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:code/menu.py", line 4, in <module>
    import email_client
  File "C:\code\email_client.py", line 4, in <module>
    import menu
  File "C:\code\menu.py", line 285, in <module>
    email_from, email_to, local_message_date, subject, body = email_client.get_email()
AttributeError: module 'email_client' has no attribute 'get_email'
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the stack trace there and looking into fixing that issue? Your error doesn't seem to be related to your question

Comment: no, I mostly consider the issue itself, just to get the user input to other file... the error is not important in this case

Comment: it seems you didnt put all the code in the question. from the error there is suppsed to be a menu.py file that used an email_client module for which doesnt have get_email.

Comment: yes, it is not full code, full code is very huge...